# New language in jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I just created a new language (nl) in a jhipster-generated site. I followed the documentation at http://jhipster.github.io/installing_new_languages.html. After doing all the steps I got JS-error: Error: Plural Function not found for locale: nl. After some fiddling I found the solution was adding

```
<script src="bower_components/messageformat/locale/nl.js"></script>
```

to index.html. Perhaps something to add to the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to run `grunt wiredep`or `gulp wiredep` which runs wiredep task that updates the list of scripts from bower_components folder in your index.html.

Comment: I definitely forgot ;-). Perhaps it's trivial for everyone working with Jhipster to do this after adding a language, but it wasn't for me. Or does it deserve a few lines in the documentation?

Comment: I just deleted the line I added to index.html and ran the grunt task you said but this doesn't add the line and thus it doesn't solve the problem. If I now  use the new language (nl) I get the JavaScript-error Plural Function not found for locale: nl in the browser. So this doen't seem to solve my problem. Any ideas on this?

Comment: My bad, it should be `grunt wiredep` or `grunt serve`

Answer (score 0):

I am adding Māori and Samoan to an application using jhipster 7.1 using angular.

I followed the instructions on the jhipster site (https://www.jhipster.tech/installing-new-languages/#how-to-add-languages-after-project-generation) to the letter. After some hair pulling and grepping using the force I managed to discover I had to add an entry for each in the file

src/main/webapp/app/config/language.constants.ts

and now I get both new entries.